# I am using rails-api and I my rake db:seed command doesn't seem to work, what has been removed that contained this functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my Gemfile:

[image]

this is the schema

[image]

this is the seed file (I am aware of the semicolon typo)

[image]

I am new to rails and not exactly sure what the function of all bundled gems were so I was wondering which gem seeded the database? Or why the way I wrote my seed.rb file is causing a rake aborts.

Comment: Please invest some time reading the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) cause you are asking a lot of questions and all of those are answered in the getting started guide...  you don't need to invest more than a couple of hours to get going... and those questions won't be answered clearly here...

Comment: Please post your external resources, since those URLs may unable to access in a later date.

Comment: this is some kind of friendly advice... if you are not familiar with rails don't start with rails api... you might find a lot of gems not working with rails-api out of the box... for example [rails admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) won't work, cause it depends on the assets pipeline which is removed from the rails api. and anything that can be achieved with rails-api, can be achieved with rails without noticeable difference (this claim is from personal experience)...

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Also pictures of code are not the way to go - stack overflow has perfectly good syntax highlighting

Comment: I figured out the problem sort of. The array of names teacher_last somehow kicked off some kinda code block and expected an 'end'. Anyways i changed the values of the array to just be 'a','b','c' etc. and it worked just fine.